# Suitable design pattern for the task

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

The database contains rows of types: `TYPE1, TYPE2, TYP3, TYPEN`

When user send request to my service and wait response I make next:

1) Call `responseService` for response:

```
@Override
public GetResponseResponse getResponse(GetResponseRequest request) 
       return responseService.getResponse(request);
}
```

2) In `responseService` prepare response:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public GetResponseResponse getResponse(GetResponseRequest request) {

    //get data from DB
    SmevMessage smevMessage = smevMessageService.findOneFinished(request.getP1(), request.getP2());

    //validate

    //create general response for all TYPES of response
     GetResponseResponse getResponseResponse = new GetResponseResponse();

    //get Builder for concrete resonse part
    UnpResponseBuilder unpResponseBuilder = unpResponseBuilderContext.getResponseBuilder(smevMessage.getRequestType());
    Element element = unpResponseBuilder.createResponse(smevMessage);

    //set part to general response
    getResponseResponse.setAny(element);

    return getResponseResponse;
}
```

I generate general response but each response has specific part for each type. I use strategy design pattern for this.

I have some imlementation of this interface:

```
public interface UnpResponseBuilder {
    Element createResponse(SmevMessage smevMessage);
}
```

and one bean - context:

```
public interface UnpResponseBuilderContext {
    UnpResponseBuilder getResponseBuilder(SmevMessageType smevMessageType);

    void setBuilder(SmevMessageType smevMessageType, UnpResponseBuilder bean);
}
```

**My question**: Is it right to use strategy for this task? Can something else be possible? If the strategy fits the right names for `UnpResponseBuilderContext`  and `UnpResponseBuilder` ?

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider this way:

```
public CreateResponseStrategy {
  public Element createResponse(SmevMessage smevMessage);
}

public FirstCreateResponseStrategy implements CreateResponseStrategy {
  public Element createResponse(SmevMessage smevMessage) {
  //logic
  }
}

public SecondCreateResponseStrategy implements CreateResponseStrategy {
  public Element createResponse(SmevMessage smevMessage) {
  //logic
  }
}
```

And later in your responseService class:

```
final ImmutableMap<String,CreateResponseStrategy> strategyMap = ImmutableMap.<String, CreateResponseStrategy>builder()
            .put("firstType", new FirstCreateResponseStrategy())
            .put("secondType",new SecondCreateResponseStrategy() )
            .build()

public GetResponseResponse getResponse(GetResponseRequest request) {

    //get data from DB
    SmevMessage smevMessage = smevMessageService.findOneFinished(request.getP1(), request.getP2());

    GetResponseResponse getResponseResponse = new GetResponseResponse();

    Element element = strategyMap.get(smevMessage.getRequestType()).createResponse(smevMessage); //additionaly check if element exists in map

    getResponseResponse.setAny(element);

    return getResponseResponse;
}
```

Maybe this approach will be better in your case. Let me if it's fine.